# Atmosphere Framework Serializer is crashed when DTO field contains | symbol

Tags: java, gwt, atmosphere

I have found an issue. When my DTO contains string with | symbol Atmosphere framework down when try to serialize. I have GWT app. And GWT works fine with "|" in the field.
Every time I send via Atmosphere field with "|" I receive "undefined" on client side and exception:

> org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor - Interceptor
>   org.atmosphere.gwt20.server.GwtRpcInterceptor@1139013 crashed.
>   Processing will continue with other interceptor.
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException:
>   This application is out of date, please click the refresh button on
>   your browser. ( Malformed or old RPC message received - expecting
>   version between 5 and 7 )

It is very seriously because within some time I have 2GB catalina.out file with exception above and tomcat stop to work

It may be useful for Atmosphere developers.

How do I fix it? because I need | symbol in the fields

Thanks

Comment: Which versions of atmosphere and GWT are you using?

Comment: @Andrew it is not fixed still. I use atmosphere-runtime-2.2.3.jar and gwt related libs 2.2.0. sorry for delay